# Find index position of partial or entire Array2 in Array1 (sequential order)

Tags: c#, .net

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
String[] Array1 = { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
                     "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "in", "the",
                     "barn" };

String[] Array2 = { "in", "the", "barn", "next", "to",
                     "the", "chickens" };


int index = Array.IndexOf(Array1, Array2);
Console.WriteLine("The first occurrence of partial Array2 is at index {0}.", index);
```

Obviously, the code above returns a value of `-1`, since the entire `Array2` is not found within Array1.

I'd like the result of `index` to be `9`.

What would be the most efficient way to find a partial array within another array?

Comment: `Array.IndexOf(Array1, Array2);` will always return `-1` because it compares each element in `Array1` with the second parameter. Obviously, a string will never be equal to a `string[]`. At the very least you'd need to search for the first occurrence of `Array2[0]`. Although, the result you describe does *not* match the actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare the first element of the second array and find it's index in the first array and then iterate over it comparing successive elements for both to check if the Array2 is completely contained in Array1.
Something like this should work:

```
String[] Array1 = { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
                 "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "in", "the",
                 "barn" };

String[] Array2 = { "in", "the", "barn", "next", "to",
                 "the", "chickens" };
                 
int index = Array.IndexOf(Array1, Array2[0]);
int subArrayFlag = 1;

if(Array2.Length + index > Array1.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array2 cannot be sub array of Array1!");
}
else
{
    for(int i =0;i<Array2.Length; i++)
    {
        if(Array.IndexOf(Array1, Array2[i]) >= 0)
        {
            if(Array2[i] == Array1[index + i])
                continue;
            else
                subArrayFlag = 0;
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            subArrayFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    if(subArrayFlag == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array2 is subarray of Array1!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array2 is not sub array of Array1!");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The first occurrence of partial Array2 is at index {0}.", index);
```

The above code can detect if the entire Array2 is contained in Array1 or not!

Comment: I was hoping to keep away from iterating through Array1, but there may be no other way.  I'm looking to use the least amount of programming possible, since after finding this occurrence, I need to check multiple other arrays to find the remainder of Array2 (if it isn't already completely contained in Array1).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loop and use `IndexOf` until you got a result:

```
String[] Array1 = { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps","over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "in", "the","barn" };

String[] Array2 = { "in", "the", "barn", "next", "to","the", "chickens" };
                 
int index = -1;
        
for (int j=0; j < Array2.Length; j++){
    index = Array.IndexOf(Array1, Array2[j]);
    if(index >= 0)
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to get the first occurrence index in the `Array1`. In this way, you don't have to worry about values that exist in `Array2` but not `Array1`.

```
private int GetFirstOccurenceIndex(string[] arr1, string[] arr2)
    {
        var keyIndexDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            var key = arr1[i];
            if (!keyIndexDict.ContainsKey(key))
                keyIndexDict[key] = i;
        }

        foreach (var key in arr2)
        {
            if (keyIndexDict.TryGetValue(key, out var arr1Index))
                return arr1Index;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Example:

```
string[] arr1 =
{
        "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps",
        "over", "the", "lazy", "dog", "in", "the",
        "barn"
};

string[] arr2 =
{
       "someValueDoesntExistInArray1", "in", "the", "barn", "next", "to",
        "the", "chickens"
};


int index = GetFirstOccurenceIndex(arr1, arr2);
Console.WriteLine("The first occurrence of partial Array2 is at index {0}.", index);
```

Comment: The problem with finding the first occurrence of Array2[0] is that I'm actually searching a very large byte array, and that first occurrence may exist in numerous places within Array1. I'm trying to figure out how much of Array2 is contained in Array1, in sequential order. I know I can search the entire array, element by element, but this seems very inefficient. There must be a more efficient and elegant approach.